# What is the definition of usability/ux problem?

Tags: usability, terminology

I am about to ask for help on [how to categorise usability/ux problems](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16954/how-to-categorise-usability-ux-problems) but after some googling I have realised that there is no standard definition of usability/ux problem. ([Defining the Usability Problem](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/about-usability/defining-the-usability-problem/), [The definition of “usability problem” is elusive](http://www.upassoc.org/conferences_and_events/upa_conference/2004/call/sample/ideamarket_usability%20problems_wilson.doc), [Is That A Usability Problem Or A Feature?](http://www.measuringusability.com/blog/problem-feature.php)).

Is there an widely accepted definition I have missed?

Answer (score 4):

There aren't many definitions of usability problem in the literature. The most reasonable I could find was by Lavery, Cockton & Atkinson ([1997](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/014492997119824)):

> A usability problem is an aspect of the system and/
>   or   a   demand   on   the   user   which   makes   it
>   unpleasant,  inefficient,  onerous  or  impossible  for
>   the  user  to  achieve  their  goals  in  typical  usage
>   situations.

Answer (score 1):

For my thesis I am encountering a similar question. I think I will try to mirror the definition of usability and state that everything interfering with it is a usability problem.

For my thesis I might use something like:

> "An usability issue in the context of this research is defined as any
> deviation from the criteria of effectiveness, efficiency, and
> satisfaction as set forth by the ISO 9241-11 standard. Specifically,
> it refers to a product characteristic or feature that hinders
> specified users from achieving their specified goals in a specified
> context of use, thereby negatively impacting the overall user
> experience."

In addition, I have found a paper which came up with an usability definition, but I will rather stick with staying as close as possible to ISO 9241-11:

Defining Usability Problems by Pavel Manakhov & Vyacheslav D. Ivanov

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to UX.SE. I'm not sure this qualifies as a definition, especially for a paper; rather, it describes what it is not. Specifically, ISO 9241-11 lacks granularity, so deviating from it could imply a wide range of interpretations.

Comment: @Devin thanks for the feedback! It makes sense what you say, I will change it then to one of the two definitions from the paper mentioned by me or Illotus.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.usabilitynet.org/tools/r_international.htm provides some of the standards around user experience and usability. Hope this helps!

Addendum: http://www.userfocus.co.uk/articles/iso-13407-is-dead.html talks about the recent work defining a standard for user centred design; this may help.

Comment: I assume one can take a definition of usability and by negating it define the usability problem. PS: What a horrible website :D.

Comment: Could you post an excerpt or summary from your link?

Comment: Well, from ISO 9241-11: Guidance on Usability (1998):"Usability: the extent to which a product can be used by specified users to achieve specified goals with effectiveness, efficiency and satisfaction in a specified context of use.". So the crux of the matter is in specifying what you want to achieve and by whom :)

Comment: UsabilityNet's quite an interesting historical artifact - as it reflects how things were back in 2003.  http://www.usabilitynet.org/about/aboutusa.htm

Answer (score 0):

One way of looking at it is to say "Is this going to drive users nuts ? Yes / No"

Problems tend to fall between 'high level' issues ( eg basic faults with say the IA or workflow) through to detailed issues (bad wording of labels / buttons that don't look like buttons etc).

Comment: I would not agree that ux is so binary.

Comment: That's just the first question though... Question 2 is 'How bad is this ?"   You can't really do the second questions until you're on the analysis phase - as you can get issues which look bad initially and then you find that users can learn a workaround.